# How can I load and display documents from a PostGRES database via SpringBoot if the type is not given when uploading?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a PostGreSQL database which stores documents among other things. A user can upload any document (Pdf, Word, TFFT, Excel, ...) via a form (React). Now my question is, how can I get this document now? The document is saved as binary code in the database. So I don't know the type of document. Here's what I tried:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/EinzelDokument/{id}")
@CrossOrigin
public void f_pp_dokument_s(HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String id)
        throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    String userEntschluesselt = entschluesselUserId(request);

    String aktuellerUser = request.getParameter("aktuellerUser");

    Connection con = DBVerbindung();
    CallableStatement properCase = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    byte[] bild = null;

    if (con != null) {

        try {
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            properCase = con.prepareCall("SELECT * FROM ppm.f_pp_projektdokument_s(?,?)");
            properCase.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
            if(aktuellerUser != null)
            {
                properCase.setString(2, aktuellerUser);
            }
            else
            {
                properCase.setString(2, userEntschluesselt);
            }
            rs = properCase.executeQuery();
            con.commit();
            byte[] decodedBytes = null;
            if (rs.next()) {

                bild = rs.getBytes("projektDokument_bin");

                String splitting = new String(bild, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

                String[] s = splitting.split(",", 2);

                decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s[1]);

            } else {

                //Which document type do I have to set here, or is this approach right at all?

                File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:Download.pdf");

                decodedBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

            }

            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setContentLength(decodedBytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (properCase != null) {
                try {
                    properCase.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I use SpringBoot in the backend and React in the frontend.

Comment: Why are you encoding it with base64? YOu shouldn't do that, just write the bytes as they are. Also what would you send if there is nothing to be found, not some random file I suspect but rather a 404. Finally don't call `close` on the outputstream that will be handled by the container.

Answer (score 1):

Best case: Alter the database to add columns where you store metadata such as the kind and version of format.

Worst case: Retrieve the document, then successively decode the data into each kind of expected document. Examine the first part of the data to find expected parts, or try using utility libraries or apps to open the data as a file while trapping for exceptions/errors.